svn commit to externals location where local path has multiple levels of (unversioned) subfolders
I have noticed a strange issue with tortoise svn. I'm using externals and use local path to create a certain folder structure to organize these externals. However when I try to commit changes to those files the commit interface does not allow me to check them. They are grayed out.
Below an example of my externals:
External defenition
When I try to commit changes the files in the subfolder Folder2/Folder21 then that file cannot be checked.
commit options
However when I use the check for modifications dialog and do a multiselect I can commit the files.
check for modifications dialog
I was reading through older posts and it looks like conclusion was that this is a bug.
But that is an issue as I relied on this multilevel checkout path to logically organize my files. Note all the externals are reusable SW components. I want to have a single point in my project to check those external defenition. Any suggestions?
